# USB Debugging with Samsung Galaxy SII

Tags: android, debugging, usb, galaxy

I used to use the Android emulator for debugging. Everything was fine. But when I tried emulator for Android 4 it was lagging so much. It was almost impossible to use it. So I tried to use USB debugging with Samsung Galaxy SII with Android 4.0.4. I've enabled USB Debugging on device, installed drivers, tried to use Kies, but it just doesn't work.
When I started debugging and selected this device in Android device chooser, it was looking like this:

**samsung-gt_i9100-0019caae19649e | N/A | 4.0.4 | --- | Online**

Then in the console it gave me this code:

```
[2013-01-28 20:30:58 - UniqueFileExplorer] Android Launch!
[2013-01-28 20:30:58 - UniqueFileExplorer] adb is running normally.
[2013-01-28 20:30:58 - UniqueFileExplorer] Performing sync
[2013-01-28 20:31:01 - UniqueFileExplorer] Uploading UniqueFileExplorer.apk onto device '0019caae19649e'
[2013-01-28 20:31:11 - UniqueFileExplorer] Failed to install UniqueFileExplorer.apk on device '0019caae19649e': timeout
[2013-01-28 20:31:11 - UniqueFileExplorer] Launch canceled!
```

So does somebody know what's the problem?

I'll be grateful for any help.

---

And sry for my bad english.

Comment: Have you tried like reboot the phone? Reboot the computer? Disable & Unable USB Debugging?

Comment: What operating system is your computer using? I have been having horrible trouble trying to get Windows 8.1 to connect to my Galaxy S3.

Answer (score 1):

Insctructions :

1 Restart phone.

2 Restart computer.

3 Check enabling "USB Debbuging" in phone settings.

4 Enable debuggable in mainfest.

Comment: I have tried this few minutes ago. I have restarted phone. Then reinstalled drivers, reinstalled Eclipse and reinstalled ADT. Then I wrote android:debuggable="true" in the <aplication> in manifest. And still doesen't work. Now when I open the device chooser it is looking like this:

0019caae19649e | N/A | unknown | --- | Offline |

Comment: Try to use another device, if you have, and give results. Ps did you restart computer ?

Comment: Yes I have restarted computer. I have HTC Desire, but it has Android 2.2. I was trying it with this device and it was worst. It hasn't even  detected it. I could try to use Galaxy SIII, but it's not my device, so I'll try it later.

Comment: I just hate this Samsung logic. It's getting worst and worst. I can't even connect this device without Samsungs Kies. That's why I still use my old HTC.

Comment: If you have kies, update it and download newest version of application and drivers. Sorry for my bad English

Comment: I'll try it. And it's ok, I'm not english speaker too.

Comment: And I have the newest Kies and actual drivers.

Comment: Nothing changed... All the same.

Comment: but wait... there is some new actualization prompted few second ago by Kies.

Comment: That awkward moment when you realize that the problem was with old framework version...

Comment: My last request for you : install adb on another computer and try again. I must know where is error .

Comment: The problem was with the framework version. It was saying that it's the newest version and one day it just prompted something like "The version of you framework is old. Do you want to instal the newest?" And now it's woring fine on both devices. So anyway thank you for help.